# Extract source comments from a Scala source file

Tags: scala, javadoc, scaladoc, doclet

I would like to programmatically extract the code comments from a Scala source file.

I have access to both the source file and objects of the classes whose comments I am interested in. I am also open to writing the comments in the Scala source file in a specific form to facilitate extraction (though still following Scaladoc conventions).

Specifically, I am not looking for HTML or similar output.

However, a json object I can then traverse to get the comments for each field would be perfectly fine (though json is not a requirement). Ideally, I would like to get a class or class member comment given its "fully qualified" name or an object of the class.

How do I best do this? I am hoping for a solution that is maintainable (without too much effort) from Scala 2.11 to Scala 3.

Appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1):

> I have access to both the source file

By this I assume you have that path to the file, which I'll represent in my code as:

```scala
val pathToFile: String = ???
```

---

### TL;DR

```scala
import scala.io.Source

def comments(pathToFile: String): List[String] = {
  def lines: Iterator[(String, Int)] = Source.fromFile(pathToFile).getLines().zipWithIndex

  val singleLineJavaDocStartAndEnds = lines.filter {
    case (line, lineNumber) => line.contains("/*") && line.contains("*/")
  }.map { case (line, _) => line }

  val javaDocComments = lines.filter {
    case (line, lineNumber) =>
      (line.contains("/*") && !line.contains("*/")) ||
      (!line.contains("/*") && line.contains("*/"))
  }
  .grouped(2).map {
    case Seq((_, firstLineNumber), (_, secondLineNumber)) =>
      lines
        .map { case (line, _) => line }
        .slice(firstLineNumber, secondLineNumber+1)
        .mkString("\n")
  }

  val slashSlashComments = lines
    .filter { case (line, _) => line.contains("//") }
    .map { case (line, _) => line }

  (singleLineJavaDocStartAndEnds ++ javaDocComments ++ slashSlashComments).toList
}
```

---

### Full explanation

First thing to do is to read the contents of the file:

```scala
import scala.io.Source

def lines: Iterator[String]  = Source.fromFile(pathToFile).getLines()

// here we preserve new lines, for Windows you may need to replace "\n" with "\r\n
val content: String = lines.mkString("\n")
// where `content` is the whole file as a `String`
```

I have made `lines` a `def` to prevent unintended results if calling `lines` multiple times. This is due to the return type of `Source.fromFile` and how it handles iterating over the file. [This comment here adds an explanation](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/io/BufferedSource.scala#L28-L32). Since you are reading source code files I think rereading the file is a safe operation to perform and won't lead to memory or performance issues.

Now that we have the `content` of the file we can begin to *filter* out the lines we don't care about. Another way of viewing the problem is that we only want to keep - filter in - the lines that are comments.

---

**Edit**:

As @jwvh rightly pointed out, where I was using `.trim.startsWith` ignored comments such as:

```scala
val x = 1 //mid-code-comments

/*fullLineComment*/
```

To address this I've replaced `.trim.startsWith` with `.contains`.

---

For single line comments this is simple:

```scala
val slashComments: Iterator[String] = lines.filter(line => line.contains("//"))
```

<s>Notice the call to `.trim` above which is important as often developers start comments intended to match the indentation of the code. `trim` removes any whitespace characters at the start of the string.</s> Now using `.contains` which catches any line with a comment starting anywhere.

---

Now we'll file multi-line comments, or JavaDoc; for example (the content is not important):

```
/**
 * Class String is special cased within the Serialization Stream Protocol.
 *
 * A String instance is written into an ObjectOutputStream according to
 * .....
 * .....
 */
```

The safest thing to do is to fine the lines that the `/*` and `*/` appear on and include all of the lines in between:

```scala
def lines: Iterator[(String, Int)] = Source.fromFile(pathToFile).getLines().zipWithIndex

val javaDocStartAndEnds: Iterator[(String, Int)] = lines.filter { 
  case (line, lineNumber) => line.contains("/*") || line.contains("*/")
}
```

`.zipWithIndex` gives us an incrementing number alongside each line. We can use these to represent the line numbers of the source file. At the moment this will give us a list of lines containing `/*` and `*/`. We need to `group` these into groups of 2 as all of these kinds of comments will have a matching pair of `/*` and `*/`. Once we have these groups we can select, using `slice`, all of the `lines` starting from the first index until the last. We want to include the last line so we do a `+1` to it.

```scala
val javaDocComments = javaDocStartAndEnds.grouped(2).map {
  case Seq((_, firstLineNumber), (_, secondLineNumber)) =>
    lines // re-calling `def lines: Iterator[(String, Int)]`
      .map { case (line, _) => line } // here we only care about the `line`, not the `lineNumber`
      .slice(firstLineNumber, secondLineNumber+1)
      .mkString("\n")
  }
```

Finally we can combine `slashComments` and `javaDocComments`:

```scala
val comments: List[String] = (slashComments ++ javaDocComments).toList
```

Regardless of the order in which we join them they won't appear in an ordered list. An improvement that could be made here would be to preserve `lineNumber` and *order* by this at the end.

I will include a "too long; didn't read" (TL;DR) version at the top so anyone can just copy the code in full without the step by step explanation.

---

> How do I best do this? I am hoping for a solution that is maintainable (without too much effort) from Scala 2.11 to Scala 3.

I hope I have answered your question and provided a useful solution.
You mentioned a JSON file as output. What I've provided is a `List[String]` in memory which you can process. If output to JSON is required I can update my answer with this.

Comment: All `val x = 1 //mid-code-comments` are missed, and this `/*fullLineComment*/` will throw off your multi-line calculation.

Comment: Hi @jwvh. That's very true! I'll update my answer to replace the `.trim.startsWith` with `contains`.

Comment: @skm Please let me know how you get on trying this solution :)

Comment: You really should test your code before posting. The current iteration fails for multiple code/comment combinations. Besides, it's not at all clear that the (now silent) OP wants a simple text parser. This business about _"given ... an object of the class"_ is confusing at best.

Comment: Thanks @jvwh. You're certainly right. I can see that the `/*fullLineComment*/` wasn't handled in the last version. Could you give examples of any other _"code/comment combinations"_ and I will update.

I intend to keep the example as simple as possible, and so intend to only handle the most common cases. Some things slip through the net still, for example URLs containing a `//`, and will appear.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this filter-file-lines by comment-type can be made to work. There are just too many corner cases and special conditions. The current code can't even handle a simple 3 line comment: `/*line1\nline2\nline3*/`

Comment: Hi jwvh. As far as I have tested this code can handle mutli-line “/*” comments and preserves the new lines in the output. As i stated previously: _” I intend to keep the example as simple as possible, and so intend to only handle the most common cases.”_. There is certainly more that could be added and might even be worth it’s own library. I’d be happy to review and defer to a solution of yours that’s more comprehensive.